# How does this declaration work: var x = new X(), Y;

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js

So I'm using ThreeJS and I want to implement their example.
This is the [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) and here is the [source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html).

But if we look at this line:

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
```

I can't get this to work in Angular, and even in Javascript I don't understand it. Any help or direction on how to use this syntax with Angular is appreciated.

Comment: Its multiple declaration combined. `var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(); var INTERSECTED;`

Comment: I feel stupid know, was thinking too much. I thought is was some import that I couldn't find. Thanks for the quick response.